# Add validator to custom form type

Tags: validation, symfony

How to add validator to **custom form type**? IBAN for exemple.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IbanValidator;

class IBANType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'iban';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //IbanValidator ???
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.1.md#deprecations) they suggest to use listeners:

> The interface FormValidatorInterface was deprecated and will be
>   removed in Symfony 2.3.
>
> If you implemented custom validators using this interface, you can
>   substitute them by event listeners listening to the
>   FormEvents::POST_BIND (or any other of the *BIND events). In case you
>   used the CallbackValidator class, you should now pass the callback
>   directly to addEventListener.

But how ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IbanValidator;

class IBANType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('iban', 'text', [
            'constraints' => [
                new IbanValidator(),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: For more information on this also check the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation

Comment: Why do I need to add new field? I get obvious error: "You cannot add children to a simple form. Maybe you should set the option "compound" to true?"